Issue on custom react component (roots, sage), not updating changes on article
so I'm a frontend coming from vue and react(so you quite have an Idea), working for the first time with wordpress and roots(small knowledge from php or laravel). So I built an article slider(articles featured) component and I thought it will be good when the user can choose already from the existing articles so...
The main Problem is after executing this code, I realized for example that... when trying to update the article title, in the article directly, this component is not getting updated as well(in the frontend...means I need to go back to the page where I used the component wait that realoads and save again...), wondering if this is a normal behavior with roots or I am doing something wrong, like I may use something like wordpress related(meaning ...native functions)
So...my .tsx cahotico looks like this:
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { __ } from "@wordpress/i18n";
import { useBlockProps } from "@wordpress/block-editor";
import { fetchArticleData, fetchArticlesList } from 'scripts/components/article';
import { TextControl, TextareaControl, SelectControl } from "@wordpress/components";

export const name = `recoupling/articleteaser`;

export const title = __('Artikel-Teaser', 'radicle');

export const category = `x`;

export const icon = `slides`;

export const apiVersion = 2;

export const attributes = {
  headline: {
    type: `string`,
    default: __(``, `radicle`),
  },
  topline: {
    type: `string`,
    default: __(``, `radicle`),
  },
  articleIds: {
    type: 'array',
    default: [],
  },
  articlesData: {
    type: 'object',
    default: {},
  },
};

export const edit = ({ attributes, setAttributes }) => {
  const [articlesList, setArticlesList] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch articles list when the component mounts
    populateSelect();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch article data when the selected article IDs change
    getArticles(attributes.articleIds);
  }, [attributes.articleIds]);

  const populateSelect = async () => {
    const selectOptions = await fetchArticlesList();
    setArticlesList(selectOptions);
    setIsLoading(false);
  }

  const getArticles = async (articleIds) => {
    const articlesData = await fetchArticleData(articleIds)
    setAttributes({ articlesData });
  };

  const handleArticleChange = (selectedArticleIds) => {
    // Set the selected article IDs to block attribute
    setAttributes({ articleIds: selectedArticleIds });
  };

  return (
    <div {...useBlockProps()}>
      <TextControl
        label={__('Überschrift', 'radicle')}
        value={attributes.headline}
        onChange={(headline) => setAttributes({ headline })}
      />
      <TextControl
        label={__('Toptext', 'radicle')}
        value={attributes.topline}
        onChange={(topline) => setAttributes({ topline })}
      />
      {isLoading ? (
        <p>{__('Loading articles...', 'radicle')}</p>
      ) : (
        <>
          <SelectControl
            multiple
            label={__('Artikel auswählen', 'radicle')}
            options={articlesList}
            value={attributes.articleIds}
            onChange={handleArticleChange}
          />
          <div className='flex flex-wrap gap-3'>
            {attributes.articleIds.map((articleId, index) => (
              <div key={index} className='"w-1/2 p-4'>
                <div className='max-h-24 overflow-hidden'>
                  <img
                    className='object-fill'
                    width="220"
                    src={attributes.articlesData[articleId] && attributes.articlesData[articleId].featuredImage
                      ? attributes.articlesData[articleId].featuredImage
                      : '../../images/backend/placeholder-loader.jpg'}
                    alt={__('Featured Image', 'radicle')}
                  />
                </div>
                <TextControl
                  label={__('Titel', 'radicle')}
                  value={attributes.articlesData[articleId] ? attributes.articlesData[articleId].title : ''}
                  disabled
                />
                <TextareaControl
                  label={__('Text', 'radicle')}
                  value={attributes.articlesData[articleId] ? attributes.articlesData[articleId].excerpt.substring(0, 208) + '...' : ''}
                  disabled
                />
                <TextControl
                  label={__('Link', 'radicle')}
                  value={attributes.articlesData[articleId] ? attributes.articlesData[articleId].link : ''}
                  disabled
                />
                <TextControl
                  label={__('Kategory', 'radicle')}
                  value={attributes.articlesData[articleId] ? attributes.articlesData[articleId].category : []}
                  disabled
                />
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export const save = ({ attributes }) => {
  return (
    <div {...useBlockProps.save()}>
      <p>{attributes.topline}</p>
      <h1>{attributes.headline}</h1>
      <div className="article-teaser__tiles swiper-wrapper">
        {attributes.articleIds.map((articleId, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="article-teaser__wrapper swiper-slide">
            <h4 className="article-teaser__headline h4-bold">{attributes.articlesData[articleId]?.title}</h4>
            <span className="article-teaser__read-time">{attributes.articlesData[articleId]?.readingTime}</span>
            <p className="article-teaser__text">{attributes.articlesData[articleId]?.excerpt}</p>
            <div className="article-teaser__bottom">
              {attributes.articlesData[articleId]?.category && attributes.articlesData[articleId]?.category.map((category, index) => (
                <span key={index}>{category}</span>
              ))}
              <a href={attributes.articlesData[articleId]?.link}>Mehr lesen </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};



Where ...
my fetchArticleData function looks like:
export const fetchArticleData = async (articleIds) => {
  // Fetch data of selected articles from WordPress API
  const fetchedData = await Promise.all(
    articleIds.map(async (articleId) => {
      const response = await fetch(`/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/${articleId}`)
                                .then(response => response.json())
                                .catch(error => console.error(error));
      return response;
    })
  );

  // Map each fetched article data to an array of promises for featured images and category names
  const promises = fetchedData.map(async (article) => {
    const imgUrlPromise = fetchFeaturedImage(article.featured_media);
    const categoryPromise = fetchCategoryNames(article.categories);
    const imgUrl = await imgUrlPromise;
    const categoryNames = await categoryPromise;
    return {
      articleData: article,
      imgUrl: imgUrl,
      categoryNames: categoryNames,
    };
  });

  // Wait for all promises to resolve
  const resolvedData = await Promise.all(promises);

  // Extract article data and store it in the state
  const articlesData = resolvedData.reduce((acc, { articleData, imgUrl, categoryNames }) => {
    acc[articleData.id] = {
      title: articleData.title.rendered,
      content: articleData.content.rendered,
      excerpt: stripHTML(articleData.excerpt.rendered),
      link: articleData.link,
      featuredImage: imgUrl,
      category: categoryNames,
    };
    return acc;
  }, {});

  return articlesData;
};

And my fetchArticlesList function looks like:
export const fetchArticlesList = async () => {
  // Fetch list of articles from WordPress API
  const fetchedData = await fetch('/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100')
                            .then(response => response.json())
                            .catch(error => console.error(error));
  // Extract article titles and IDs
  const articles = fetchedData.map(article => ({
    label: article.title.rendered,
    value: article.id,
  }));
  // Set articles list to state

  return articles;
};

And simple feed my select with the Article Title Name and
And my .blade.php code looks like this(although I think in this particular case it does not play the main role of the problem...)
@props([
    'headline'=> '',
    'topline'=> '',
    'articlesData' => [],
    'class' => '',
])

<div class="article-slider__bg">
<div class="article-slider__header">
<p class="p-big-bold">{{ $topline }}</p>
<h2 class="article-slider__headline">{{ $headline }}</h2>
</div>
<div class="article-slider {{ $class }} js-articleslider swiper">
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
    @foreach($articlesData as $article)
        @if (isset($article['title']) && isset($article['excerpt']))
                <div class="article-teaser swiper-slide">
                @if (isset($article['featuredImage']) )
                <div class="article-teaser__image">
                    <div> {{ $data['article']['see_more'] }}</div>

                    <img src="{{ $article['featuredImage'] }}" alt="Cover {{ $article['title'] }}" />
                </div>
                @endif
                <div class="article-teaser__content">
                <h4 class="article-teaser__headline h4-bold">{{ $article['title'] }}</h4>
                    <div class="article-teaser__text"><p>{{ $article['excerpt'] }}</p></div>
                    <div class="article-teaser__bottom">
                        <div class="category-container">
                        @foreach($article['category'] as $category)
                        <span>{{ $category }}</span>
                         @endforeach
                        </div>
                        <div class="link-container"><a href="{{ $article['link'] }}">Mehr lesen </a></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

        @endif
    @endforeach
    </div>
    <div class="article-slider__navegation">
        <div>
            <div class="swiper-button-prev before:content-arrowLeftSlider"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next before:content-arrowRightSlider"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

Thank you in Advance for your help, if you need further information, please let me know...
